# IAP restart subscription failing

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

We have a user who is trying to restart his monthly subscription in the app that expired over a year ago. Unfortunately when adding the new request to the request for the product purchase to the SKPaymentQueue it is showing the most recent transaction in the queue has a restored state.

We are then attempting to check validate the users receipt, which features now valid transactions in the past year.

Does anyone have any ideas why this restored status is being applied to the purchase?